# Am I bungling glVertexAttribPointer(), or is my HD6480G driver likely to blame and what recourse do I have?

Tags: linux, opengl, glfw, vao

I'm trying to utilize VAO (vertex array object) functionality in an opengl context.  My non vao buffer objects draw fine, but when I bind my VAO and draw, no object is drawn. I am basically using some example code and feel it should work.  But I have a hybrid dual graphics card setup that's a bit old and has been the source of deep seated grief and regret and several turns in the past, I have researched and have unearthed hints that it could be related to it or synchronization with the gpu and resource calls.. But need an expert to sort things out for me and define the lay of the land.

I am using opengl version is..3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.8 on linux Ubuntu. I have turned off all other code and ran the setup and do while drawcalls quite diligently.  I have set error callbacks and played with the values of
`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);`
which I assume is the source of my greif.  I have read these are not enabled by default and are activated in the draw call and initiakization which I will expose below.

This is where I create my VAO

```
void createSquare() {
  float vertices1[] = {
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // top left
    };
    unsigned int indices1[] = {  // note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3,  // first Triangle
        1, 2, 3   // second Triangle
    };
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
      glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
      glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
      // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
      glBindVertexArray(VAO);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices1), vertices1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
      glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices1), indices1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

          glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
      glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

      // note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

      // remember: do NOT unbind the EBO while a VAO is active as the bound element buffer object IS stored in the VAO; keep the EBO bound.
      //glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

      // You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other
      // VAOs requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
      glBindVertexArray(0);


}
```

And this is the totality of what's in my draw function..

```
glUseProgram(programID);


glBindVertexArray(VAO); 
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

As I say before, this error is thrown---> GL_INVALID_VALUE in glVertexAttribPointerARB(idx)  and the square is not drawn.

Comment: Ok, maybe i was wrong about the black screen, that was happening a bit earlier, It's just not drawing the square.  I tried glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);  still getting an error.

Comment: ...how were you drawing *anything* without VAOs before in a Core context?

Comment: generated a bunch of buffer objects and set the textures.. then 
  glUseProgram(programID);
  glBindVertexArray(VAO);
   //glBindVertexArray(vertexbuffer);
 // someOpenGLFunctionThatDrawsOurTriangle();




        // Draw the triangles !
            glDrawElements(
                GL_TRIANGLES,      // mode
                indices.size(),    // count
                GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,   // type
                (void*)0           // element array buffer offset
            );

Comment: Maybe that's the clue I need, perhaps my machine cannot operate in a core context so It's holding me back and I dont see it.  Are you saying that my hd6480g driver  is likely at fault?

Comment: I thought I was using the core profile I set these during init.  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);// minimum versions to use
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);// minimum versions to use
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

Comment: $ glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.2.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 18.2.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

Answer (score 0):

It appears I am not in core context..so, it's likely the answer to this mess.  Thanks for the quick responses.